# Android Runtime permissions in marshmallow for Android Camera application

Tags: android

In Android marshmallow android introduced  runtime permissions. 
Here my question is Do Android system application such as Camera, Phonebook need to ask for permission like any other non system applications.
Does android system application have some privileges.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, they need to ask. You can check their permissions in settings

Comment: You must ask for every permission on runtime for any feature that requires [dangerous permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to run system applications (by Intent), then you must request the appropriate permissions, except [Normal Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html).

**NOTE**. And you must remember that the user can **at any time** revoke the granted permissions.